# Is dependency injection possible in symfony annotations?

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I can create my own annotation in symfony just with

```
/** @Annotation */
class MyAnnotation
{
    public function __concruct(array $params)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and use it inside a controller (for example)

```
class MyController
{
    /** @MyAnnotation(foo="bar") */
    public function fooAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Can I inject into my MyAnnotation class some other services?

Comment: You can make listener with services and do logic there: http://hoangnd.me/blog/using-custom-annotation-in-symfony-controller

Comment: Thank you very much, but my question is different.

Comment: What is different, you cannot inject services until you class is a service.

Comment: if I use your custom annotation, I cannot send variables like `@MyAnnotation(foo="bar")`. In your link there is no need of annotations.

Comment: And again "The event listener will override the response of indexAction and print out 2 annotation messages.". I do not want to override Response.